# A story about a skinned animal/fur coat in a closet with a bone in its tail, gained more bones by the character feeding it fruit from a tree

Tags: story-identification

First of all, I'm not quite sure if I'm putting this in the right section, I'm fairly new to stack exchange and I couldn't find anywhere else. I'm sorry if this isn't the right category.

This was a book that was read to me about 6 years ago in school, I can't remember the author, the book name, not even the character name.. But what I do remember is the character found a skinned animal/fur coat in a closet and there was a bone at the end of the tail. The fox spoke to the character and said to put a fruit from a tree in its mouth and every next day, the character would find more and more bones in the tail and through the body, etc. That's all I can remember.

If anyone has an idea of what book it may be, please let me know and thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems on-topic. There are definitely fantasy elements here.

Comment: Do you remember the approximate year that you read this book?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Knew I read this somewhere.....Someone postulated the [TV adaptation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Round_the_Twist_episodes) as an ID for a [Movies & TV SE question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/30603/short-movie-on-pbs-in-the-70s-with-a-fox-stole-that-comes-to-life).

It's a short story called ***"Grandad's Gifts"*** from a short story collection named [Unbearable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbearable_(book)) by Paul Jennings, published in 1990.

Also available as a [standalone picture book](http://www.pauljennings.com.au/books_detail.asp?pid=1723).
[image]

A boy finds a fox stole in his grandad's cupboard. He picks lemons from a tree outside and gives them to the fox-- which comes back to life.

[Summary](http://www.librarything.com/work/950243):

> Shane's father promised his own father years ago that he would never
>   open the locked cupboard in his bedroom. Now that they are moving into
>   the Grandad's old house, Shane's father expects Shane to keep that
>   promise. Shane's father also points out the two lemon trees in the
>   back garden. A big one and a small one. The big tree, laden with
>   lemons, marks where Grandad shot a fox and buried its remains. The
>   other tree is shrivelled with only two lemons on it. Under his bed,
>   Shane finds a loose board -- and a rusty key hidden. It unlocks the
>   forbidden cupboard! Inside is a dried fox. Then Shane notices the old
>   photograph in the kitchen of long-dead Grandad and a dried fox. That
>   night Shane dreams of the lemon tree and, as if on command, goes out
>   and gets a lemon and puts it in the dead fox's mouth. Feeding lemons
>   to the fox brings it back to life! All except for real eyes. Shane
>   knows it's the last two lemons the fox needs. All that is left behind
>   when the fox returns to the wild are two glass eyes. The fox looks
>   back at Shane with its clear blue eyes (the color of Grandad's eyes)
>   and seems to say 'Thank you. And farewell.' The little lemon tree
>   dies. And Shane's father happens to mention, "It's never grown well,
>   and it should have. Because we planted it on Grandad's grave."

Comment: That's a pretty creepy story

Comment: @Daft certainly is.

Comment: I though it was ringing a bell in my head bet I saw it on round the twist though!

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much, this is the one.